# Free sites for testing POST REST API calls?

Tags: automated-testing, rest-api, rest-assured

My previous company was testing only GET calls. Now I need to practice with other type of calls (POST, PUT, DELETE).

I can not find any site that is free for POST API calls, and that it have up to date documentation with the API explanations.

I have tried with google maps (they are not allowing free authorization any more), Jira change authentication process to OAUTH2 and not provided the best documentation for resolving it, this site https://reqres.in/ you can do the post, and get some response, but when you try to GET call for same data that you posted, it is empty.

I fill like I do not have appropriate playground. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.postman.com/explore

it have many collections and examples, you can create a account and fork it and use.

or create your own mock server here and learn:

https://app.mocklab.io/

Comment: Thank you for the link it seems that there are so much public API-s, some of them must work. :-)

Comment: mocklab is very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 10):

As this answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9770981/1725871) states.

https://httpbin.org/ allows you to echo back your request, to see that it does what you expect.

this is the list of services

It echoes the data used in your request for any of these types:

- https://httpbin.org/anything Returns most of the below.
- https://httpbin.org/ip Returns Origin IP.
- https://httpbin.org/user-agent Returns user-agent.
- https://httpbin.org/headers Returns header dict.
- https://httpbin.org/get Returns GET data.
- https://httpbin.org/post Returns POST data.
- https://httpbin.org/put Returns PUT data.
- https://httpbin.org/delete Returns DELETE data
- https://httpbin.org/gzip Returns gzip-encoded data.
- https://httpbin.org/status/:code Returns given HTTP Status code.
- https://httpbin.org/response-headers?key=val Returns given response headers.
- https://httpbin.org/redirect/:n 302 Redirects n times.
- https://httpbin.org/relative-redirect/:n 302 Relative redirects n times.
- https://httpbin.org/cookies Returns cookie data.
- https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/:name/:value Sets a simple cookie.
- https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/:user/:passwd Challenges HTTPBasic Auth.
- https://httpbin.org/hidden-basic-auth/:user/:passwd 404'd BasicAuth.
- https://httpbin.org/digest-auth/:qop/:user/:passwd Challenges HTTP Digest Auth.
- https://httpbin.org/stream/:n Streams n–100 lines.
- https://httpbin.org/delay/:n Delays responding for n–10 seconds.

Comment: Httpbin site provides also docker image to setup same Service locally.

Comment: I've chosen https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ , is still working and lets you to test both GET and POST, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

### https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

#### {JSON}

Free fake API for testing and prototyping.
Powered by JSON Server + LowDB

As of Dec 2020, serving ~1.8 billion requests each month.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good website for that: https://restful-api.dev/

You can send POST, PUT, DELETE, etc. They actually store the data which you create via POST. So, if you create an object using POST, you can access it via GET after that. You can also do the same if you want to GET multiple objects at once